# Android Studio NDK workaround

Tags: java, android, c++, android-studio, android-ndk

I am trying to integrate the NDK project where Android Studio tells me I can have a workaround by:

> Warning: Native C/C++ source code is found, but it seems that NDK
>   option is not configured.  Note that if you have an Android.mk, it is
>   not used for compilation.  The recommended workaround is to remove the
>   default jni  source code directory by adding:
>
> ```
> android {
>     sourceSets {
>         main {
>             jni.srcDirs = []
>     }
> } }
> ```
>
> to build.gradle, manually compile the code with ndk-build, and then
>   place the resulting shared object in src/main/jniLibs

so after my ndk build, i find that there are two places where I can find .so files in armeabi-v7a,mips and x86 folders

```
/libs
/obj/local
```

**so which folders from above two contain the actual .so files to be copied?**

And do I have to configure anything else to make this work? I imported the project via Android Studio's import ADT method.
Thank you!

Comment: You need to place it under `libs` folder. There can be total 4 folder will create if you follow ndk compilation. under each folder you can place your `.so` file

Comment: I have done ndk-build and it created the .so files in two folders, what I wanted to ask was which of those two folders(/libs or /obj/local) from to copy my '.so' files into my main Android Studio project.

Comment: As per my understanding `obj/local/` has everything you have compiled including `o.d` and executable file but lib has only `.so` file. i.e obj/local  has a fresh copy of `.so` file. These is the default environment used for compilation `. NDK_LIBS_OUT=./Libs NDK_OUT=./obj`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The suggested workaround assumes that you manually copy the contents of **libs** directory to **src/main/jniLibs**.

Alternative workaround is to add the following enchantment to the **build.gradle** file:

```
jniLibs.srcDirs = [ 'libs' ]
```

This line goes together with **jni.srcDirs** as stated in the message you quote.

Comment: Also note that the libraries are not contained directly within the `jniLibs.srcDirs` directories, but rather within sub-directories named as the architecture of the compiled library.  For example, with a library named `libdetection_based_tracker.so`, and `jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jniLibs']`, your file paths may be: `src\main\jniLibs\armeabi-v7a\libdetection_based_tracker.so` and `src\main\jniLibs\x86\libdetection_based_tracker.so`.

Comment: So the .so files in the /obj/local are not the ones I need to point to? One of the comments in the question stated that they had more fresh copy of .so files and it also has the same set of .so files but with different size from  those in /libs directory.

Comment: The files under **/obj** are important for debugging. When we use **ndk-stack** or **addr2line**, we point to the "fat" copies under **/obj**. The linker (started from **ndk-build**) produces its output in **/obj**. After that, **ndk-build** starts **strip** process that copies a *stripped* version of the libraries to **/libs** folder. You don't need all debug symbol information to run the program on your device, but you can enjoy this significant gain of APK size.

Comment: Thank you! that was the answer I was looking for.